# JMS Serializer ignores mappings for Knp Paginator

Tags: jmsserializerbundle, knppaginator

I have problem with exclusion of some KNP Paginator properties with JMS Serializer.

First, this is included in composer.json

```
...
"jms/serializer-bundle": "~0.13",
"knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
...
```

I'm paginating CrmContacts entity and exclusion policy for that entity works well. I also added yml file for KNP Paginator like this:

config.yml

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            KNPPB:
                namespace_prefix: 'Knp\\Bundle\\PaginatorBundle'
                path: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/serializer/Knp
```

inside app/Resources/serializer/Knp folder I've created Pagination.SlidingPagination.yml:

```
Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPagination:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
        properties:
            items:
                expose: true
                access_type: public_method
                accessor:
                    getter: getItems
                type: array
                serialized_name:
                    payload
            currentPageNumber:
                expose: true
                serialized_name:
                    page
            numItemsPerPage:
                expose: true
                serialized_name:
                    items
            totalCount:
                expose: true
                serialized_name:
                    totalItems
```

and this is logic for returning serialized data:

```
public function getContactsAction(Request $request)
{

    $limit = $request->query->getInt('l', 10);
    $page = $request->query->getInt('p', 1);

    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');

    $contacts = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('AcmeContactsBundle:CrmContact')
        ->getContacts();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $contacts,
        $page,
        $limit
    );

    return new Response(
        $serializer->serialize(
            $pagination,
            'json',
            SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(['Default'])
        ),
        Response::HTTP_OK,
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ]
    );

}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting all properties from Knp Paginator in response:

```
{
    "currentPageNumber": 1,
    "numItemsPerPage": 10,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            ...
        }
    ],
    "totalCount": 3,
    "paginatorOptions": {
        "pageParameterName": "page",
        "sortFieldParameterName": "sort",
        "sortDirectionParameterName": "direction",
        "filterFieldParameterName": "filterField",
        "filterValueParameterName": "filterValue",
        "distinct": true
    },
    "customParameters": [],
    "route": "acmeContactsGetContacts",
    "params": [],
    "pageRange": 5,
    "template": "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig",
    "sortableTemplate": "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig",
    "filtrationTemplate": "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:filtration.html.twig"
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The properties that you want to map are owned by Knp\Component\Pager\Pagination\AbstractPagination.

You also want to hide the rest of properties, so you will have to configure both classes.

I've just tried the following and it's working for me.

---

app/config/config.yml

```
jms_serializer:
metadata:
    directories:
        KnpPaginatorBundle:
            namespace_prefix: Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle
            path: %kernel.root_dir%/config/serializer/KnpPaginatorBundle
        KnpPager:
            namespace_prefix: Knp\Component\Pager
            path: %kernel.root_dir%/config/serializer/KnpPager
```

app/config/serializer/KnpPager/Pagination.AbstractPagination.yml

```
Knp\Component\Pager\Pagination\AbstractPagination:
exclusion_policy: ALL
properties:
    items:
        expose: true
        access_type: public_method
        accessor:
            getter: getItems
        type: array
        serialized_name:
            payload
    currentPageNumber:
        expose: true
        serialized_name:
            page
    numItemsPerPage:
        expose: true
        serialized_name:
            items
    totalCount:
        expose: true
        serialized_name:
            totalItems
```

app/config/serializer/KnpPaginatorBundle/Pagination.SlidingPagination.yml

```
Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPagination:
exclusion_policy: ALL
```

---

Don't forget to clear the cache before testing.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of serializing all the pagination object, try to serialize only the data and items, like this:

```
$result = array(
  'data' => $pagination->getItems(),
  'meta' => $pagination->getPaginationData());

return new Response(
    $serializer->serialize(
        $result,
        'json',
        SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(['Default'])
    ),
    Response::HTTP_OK,
    ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',]
);
```