# Override KNP Paginator entity

Tags: php, symfony, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

I am currently working with KNP Paginator to paginate results. 
I get serialize paginator object and get response in following form:

```
  "current_page_number": 1
  "num_items_per_page": 5
  "items": [5]
  "total_count": 35
  "paginator_options": {
  "pageParameterName": "page"
  "sortFieldParameterName": "sort"
  "sortDirectionParameterName": "direction"
  "filterFieldParameterName": "filterField"
  "filterValueParameterName": "filterValue"
  "distinct": true
  }-
  "custom_parameters": [0]
  "route": "api_tags_list"
  "params": [0]
  "page_range": 5
  "template": "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig"
  "sortable_template": 
  "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig"
  "filtration_template": 
  "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:filtration.html.twig"
```

Is it possible to override KNP paginator entity so that response will not include `templates` but included `total number of pages`?

Desired output:

```
  "current_page_number": 1
  "num_items_per_page": 5
  "items": [5]
  "total_count": 35
  "paginator_options": {
  "pageParameterName": "page"
  "sortFieldParameterName": "sort"
  "sortDirectionParameterName": "direction"
  "filterFieldParameterName": "filterField"
  "filterValueParameterName": "filterValue"
  "distinct": true
  }-
  "custom_parameters": [0]
  "route": "api_tags_list"
  "params": [0]
  "page_range": 5
  "total_page_number": 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed in two way:

1) Define the serialization of the KNP paginator defining what you want to display as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935638/2270041) (you could also define the prev/next route with a jms subscriber or with banzigahatoas bundle). The result in the controller will be:

```
 $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $data =
            $paginator->paginate(
                $query, /* query NOT result */
                2 /*page number*/,
                2/*limit per page*/
            );
         return $data;
```

2) Or managed by hand the result in this manner:

```
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $data =
            $paginator->paginate(
                $query, /* query NOT result */
                2 /*page number*/,
                2/*limit per page*/
            );
        return [
            'items' => $data->getItems(),
            'pagination' => $this->paginationToArray($data)
        ];
```

Where paginatorToArray method is something like [this](https://github.com/mbiagetti/acme-social-backend/blob/master/src/Acme/SocialBundle/Service/ApiAdapter.php#L134).

Hope this help

Comment: first option looks like really good solution, bit it doesn't work for me. I cleared cache, but still don't get expected result. second option doesn't suit my current controller response format. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hi @blahblah very stange, I'm sorry... I used both in my projects.. let me know how you solved. Good luck